# ListView ToolTip flickers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, tooltip, flicker

I have a ListView with certain id values. Am using the movemove method to display additional details about this id in a tooltip.

The code was written in VB2003 and it worked perfectly till now. Recently we migrated to VB2008.

Now the tool tip flickers. Details below.

Hope this is an easy one for the .NET big boys. I am a Java EE developer, so I've got very little (no) clue about what I've done wrong.

Compiler setting:
Target framework .NET 2.0

Code:

```
Dim m_HoveredItem As ListViewItem

Private Sub cancellationList_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles CancellationList.MouseMove
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = Me.CancellationList.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)

    If Not lvi Is m_HoveredItem Then
        m_HoveredItem = lvi
        If lvi Is Nothing Then
            Me.cancelrejectToolTip.SetToolTip(Me.CancellationList, "")
        Else
            Dim orderText As String() = lvi.Text.Split("(")
            Dim orderRef As Integer = CInt(orderText(0).Trim)
            Dim orderIsin As String
            Dim orderDesc As String
            Dim order As AppOrder= New AppOrder(_server, orderRef)
            orderIsin = order.Isin
            orderDesc = order.OrderDescription
            cancelrejectToolTip.SetToolTip(Me.CancellationList, (orderRef.ToString & "/" & orderIsin & "/" & orderDesc))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the mouse movement keeps moving over the visible tooltip, making it hide, but then the mouse move makes it visible again, and the cycle continues.  Easiest way is to just offset the location of the tooltip using the Show method:

```
Private Sub cancellationList_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                       ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                       Handles CancellationList.MouseMove
  Dim lvi As ListViewItem = Me.CancellationList.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)

  If Not lvi Is m_HoveredItem Then
    m_HoveredItem = lvi
    If lvi Is Nothing Then
      Me.cancelrejectToolTip.Hide(Me.CancelleationList) 
    Else
      Dim orderText As String() = lvi.Text.Split("(")
      Dim orderRef As Integer = CInt(orderText(0).Trim)
      Dim orderIsin As String
      Dim orderDesc As String
      Dim order As AppOrder= New AppOrder(_server, orderRef)
      orderIsin = order.Isin
      orderDesc = order.OrderDescription

      cancelrejectToolTip.Show(orderRef.ToString & "/" & orderIsin & "/" & orderDesc, _
                               Me.Cancellationlist, _
                               New Point(e.X + 16, e.Y + 16))
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that worked wonders. Thanks. I actually had come across this suggestions in a thread but didn't use show, instead kept looking for a set method to set the position. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @siddheshjog Forgot to mention that I also changed it to use the `Hide(...)` method.